# CTE recursive query loops

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have many to many  table Dependency, that has two columns SourceId and DependsOnId. I would really like to get recursively all dependents for given Id.

For now I have next query:

```
with Rec(SourceId, DependsOnId)
as (
 select SourceId, DependsOnId from [dbo].[Dependency]
 union all
 select Rec.SourceId, Rec.DependsOnId
 from [dbo].[Dependency] d
 join [dbo].[Dependency] dd
 on d.SourceId = dd.DependsOnId and d.DependsOnId = dd.SourceId 
 join Rec 
 on Rec.DependsOnId = d.SourceId

)
SELECT * FROM Rec
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 30000);
```

But it prefers to loop infinitely. I understand why, it is because of mirror dependencies like 1->2 and 2->1. So I need such cases to be handled only once.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you share with us some sample input data?

Comment: If your data has cycles, I'm affraid CTEs aren't to work very well for you - you basically need to do a `distinct` over the union, and I'm not sure if CTEs support that (you could try, though :)). A temporary table might work better.

Comment: @Luaan thank you, so many tries and nothing. Turned out I followed wrong way. I'll try to use temporary table, could you push me in right direction? Because seems like i need recursion anyway, but you said that CTE is not an option.

Comment: The main idea is that you would have an "infinite" loop which would keep adding unique rows to your temporary table (a simple insert ... select with a join on the temporary table should work - using a `level` column helps to keep track of your head, each new loop just increments `level` and tries to add rows that depend on the previous level, as long as they aren't already in the temporary table), until there's no row you can insert anymore. This way you'll have a table full of unique rows.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  You have too many joins, I think.  Try this:

```
with Rec(SourceId, DependsOnId) as (
      select SourceId, DependsOnId
      from [dbo].[Dependency]
      union all
      select Rec.SourceId, d.DependsOnId
      from Rec join
           [dbo].[Dependency] d
           on Rec.DependsOnId = d.SourceId
    )
SELECT *
FROM Rec
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 30000);
```

The subquery is now adding one dependencies at one additional depth when it goes through the loop.

Note:  this can still have infinite recursion, if your data has cycles in it.  I would recommend that you set up a SQL Fiddle, if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thing is you cant use multiple references to CTE call. So you func is with errors)

Comment: @IlyaLivshits . . . I accidentally left a line of code in the answer.

Comment: anyway, as you said I have cycles. So, not a solution)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ParentID INT = 2;

WITH CTE AS(
        SELECT  SourceId, DependsOnId
        FROM    [dbo].[Dependency]
        WHERE   SourceId = @ParentID  --<-- Given Parent id 

        UNION ALL

        SELECT  t.SourceId, t.DependsOnId
        FROM    [dbo].[Dependency] t 
        INNER JOIN
                CTE c ON t.DependsOnId = c.SourceId
)
SELECT  *
FROM    CTE
```

Comment: Unfortunately unsuccessful( It returns only first level dependents. But thank you anyway